# Централизация проверок и действий в одном месте

Tags: c#, архитектура, инспекция-кода, шаблоны-проектирования, рефакторинг

Вопрос на инспекцию кода.

В проекте есть в доменном слое сущность Order (заказ) на которой находится большое число методов, проверяющих можно ли произвести какое-либо действие с заказом и его дочерними данными (например, комментариями или позициями заказа):

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public OrderStatus ; { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderPosition> OrderPositions { get; set; }

    // ... и прочие данные заказа

    public bool CanDeleteOrder(int userId)
    {
        if (this.Status == OrderStatus.Open && this.IsManagerOrParticipant(userId))
            return true;

        if (this.Status == OrderStatus.Locked && this.IsManager(userId))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public bool IsOrderPositionsReadOnly(int userId)
    {
        if (this.Status == OrderStatus.Archieved)
            return true;

        if (this.Status == OrderStatus.Open && this.IsParticipant(userId))
            return false;

        if (this.IsManager(userId))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public bool CanCreateOrderPositions(int userId)
    {
        return !this.IsOrderPositionsReadOnly(userId);
    }

    public bool CanUpdateOrderPositions(int userId)
    {
        return !this.IsOrderPositionsReadOnly(userId);
    }

    public bool CanDeleteOrderPositions(int userId)
    {
        return !this.IsOrderPositionsReadOnly(userId);
    }

    private bool IsManager(int userId)
    {
        return this.GroupBuying.ManagerId == userId;
    }

    private bool IsManagerOrParticipant(int userId)
    {
    }
}
```

При этом собственно действия вынесены в сервисы:

```
public class OrderService
{
    public OrderService(IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
        this.OrderRepository = orderRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(orderRepository));
    }

    private readonly IOrderRepository OrderRepository;

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(int orderId, int userId)
    {
        var order = await this.OrderRepository.FindAsync(orderId);

        if (order == null)
            throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to find Order with Id '{orderId}'.");

        if (!order.CanDeleteOrder(userId))
            throw new ApplicationException("CanDeleteOrder is false.");

        return await this.OrderRepository.DeleteAsync(order);
    }

    ....
}
```

Ну, работает - но мне как-то такой подход кажется не совсем удачным вот с какой точки зрения: хочется гарантировать что любое действие будет обязательно содержать проверку возможности этого действия.

Я имею ввиду, что снаружи класса Order может появиться некоторый класс, который захочет вызвать например удаление при этом не вызвав проверки CanDeleteOrder (или вызвав какие-то свои проверки, свою логику проверок) -- а хочется, что вся логика по определению возможно ли удаление осталась в одном центральном месте.

Какие есть предложения по организации кода с учётом подобных требований?

У меня самого есть два варианта, как это можно сделать и оба  содержат какие-то изьяны.

Первый вариант - перенести удаление из сервиса в сам класс заказа, при этом Order получит в зависимости репозитории для того, чтобы завершить удаление из базы. Не нравится то, что сущности по правилам не должны ничего знать о персистентности. (Возможно, я не очень хорошо понимаю это правило?)

Второй вариант - перенести проверку возможности удаления в сервис. Модель становится анемичной, без всякой логики, сервисы сильно распухают от логики.

Comment: третий вариант: оставить как есть, если кто-то пользуется недокументированными возможностями - его проблемы

Comment: как вариант, сделать статический класс, который принимает на вход экземпляр объекта и проверяет на корректность. И всю проверку вынести туда. Таким образом централизация проверок будет и можно вызывать необходимые методы где угодно (например контроллеры, viewModelы.. сервисы)

Comment: @SultanovShamil Цель не "централизовать проверки", а "централизовать проверки подближе к действиям": в языке нет конструкций, которые явно позволяют указать, что некий метод обязан вызываться только после проверок -- поэтому хоть как-то снизить возможность выстрелить себе в ногу можно только собрав связанную логику поближе друг к другу, чтобы она была понятной.

Answer (score 1):

Если рассудить логически, то `CanDeleteOrder` не должен находиться в сущности Order, так как не понятно, откуда эту заявку удалить. Если я создал `var orders = new List<Order>();` отсюда можно удалять? Все эти методы необходимы для работы сервиса, означают, что через сервис нельзя удалить заявку, следовательно у сервиса и должен находиться метод для проверки можно ли заявку удалить через него. И да, по хорошему было бы сделать еще интерфейс IOrderService, чтобы [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) и все такое, вдруг вы захотите использовать другую реализацию сервиса.

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    public OrderService(IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
        this.OrderRepository = orderRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(orderRepository));
    }

    private readonly IOrderRepository OrderRepository;

    public bool CanDeleteOrder(Order order, int userId) //Возможно просто CanDelete, тут то понятно, что речь об Order, но для понимания, перенес как было 
    {
        if (order.Status == OrderStatus.Open && order.IsManagerOrParticipant(userId))
            return true;

        if (order.Status == OrderStatus.Locked && order.IsManager(userId))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(int orderId, int userId)
    {
        var order = await this.OrderRepository.FindAsync(orderId);

        if (order == null)
            throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to find Order with Id '{orderId}'.");

        if (!CanDeleteOrder(order, userId))
            throw new ApplicationException("Order can not be deleted");

        return await this.OrderRepository.DeleteAsync(order);
    }
}
```